# USB2VGA device not listed as output device

Tags: usb, xorg, vga, xrandr, xserver

When I type `xrandr` the usb2vga device "Magic Control Technology Corp. (USB2VGA dongle)" does not show up.

- A reboot with the device plugged in doesn't change it.
- The kernel.log shows that it has been found (http://pastebin.com/Qbj6SP0M).
- `lsusb` shows that it is still active (with ID 0711:5100).

I'd like to use it under Ubuntu 12.10 for an additional screen.